# Easier way of communicating between a website and an application

Tags: mysql, client, communication

So I client of mine is asking me to design a website where people can order food. My client would have a desktop application (that I am also developing) which should get all the orders from the website and fire some sound alarm when there is a new one, so that he can start cooking what the user ordered and get ready for the delivery.

I'm thinking a way to develop this and at first glance I was going for a MySQL database approach. The webpage stores the user order in the database and then the desktop app remotely queries the database to see if there is a new one.

The problem with this is that there are few hostings providing remote queries to databases, and here in Spain there are practically none.

I'm sure there must be another way of doing this without using databases but I just can find it. Anyone could bring some light to this matter?

Comment: No popnoodles, he was kidding, because this is a comedy site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "standard" solution to this is to expose a URL on your web server that's just to be used by the desktop application. That URL returns an easy to parse (typically JSON) string indicating new orders - it typically gets those order by querying the database. So you're still using a database, but instead of the desktop querying it directly it queries the web server which queries the database and returns the result. For example:

GET http://your.site.com/orders-after/2014-05-22-08-00

would return all orders placed after 08:00 on 5/22/2014 in some easy to handle format like:

```
{
   "order": "cheeseburger",
   "amount": 10.20
}
```

You could also use Websockets or something so that the web server can push new orders to the desktop instead of having the desktop poll the web server.